# Flask_mail connection refused

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I'm trying to send email but it shows error like under. can anyone tell me what's wrong? above is the original code. I have tried with both `TLS 465` and `SMTP 587`. but the result was same, connection refused.

Here is Code:

```
    from threading import Thread
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_mail import Mail, Message
    from config import config
    from instance.config import *

    app = Flask(__name__)


    def send_async_email(msg):
        mail = Mail(app) 
        with app.app_context():
            mail.send(msg)
    def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
        app.config.from_object(config['default'])
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

        msg = Message(MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX + ' ' + subject,
                      sender=MAIL_SENDER, recipients=[to],html='templates/email/inform.html')
        thrmail = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[msg])
        thrmail.start()
        return thrmail
```

Here is Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:                                             
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                        
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner   
        self.run()                                                            
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run                
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)                             
      File "/data/evsim/pub_api/e_mail.py", line 13, in send_async_email      
        mail.send(msg)                                                        
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 491, in send                                                                    
        with self.connect() as connection:                                    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 144, in __enter__                                                               
        self.host = self.configure_host()                                     
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 158, in configure_host                                                          
        host = smtplib.SMTP(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)                 
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__             
        (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)                                
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect              
        self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)                
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket          
        self.source_address)                                                  
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection     
        raise err                                                             
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection     
        sock.connect(sa)                                                      
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Do you have a mail(smtp) service running locally?

Answer (score 0):

first of all for sending mail using flask-mail u should have  theses things

1.smtp server  - if u have a local smtp server like postfix no problem or ur have to have testing mail server  go to this link and create  free account to get the free smtp server ip and config details .....https://mailtrap.io

2. you  have to open the smtp port in ur firewall.

after configuring those try to run ur programme  with correct config details

Comment: I'm using google smtp service and it is working well with other services..

Comment: did u open the port in  your os firewall.and what is the port ur using for smtp

Comment: check above service and whether its working with ur code....if its work then check ur config file whether u have writtten the correct details of the gmail smtp server correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration worked for me. Please try with this configuration :

```
MAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com'
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USE_TLS = False
MAIL_USE_SSL= True
MAIL_USERNAME = 'yourmail@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
```

Also do not forget to allow "less secure app" to access your account. Refer this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).